# Prove that $\bar S = S \cup [\text{Accumulation points of S}]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $S \subseteq E$, where $E$ is a metric space. Then

> $x\in S$ is an accumulation point of $S$ iff there is a sequence $x_n \in S$ such that $\lim x_n = x$ and $a_n \not = a_m$ for $n \not = m$. (Real Analysis, T. Terzioğlu, p24)

[image]
[image]

And we already know that

> $x\in \bar S$ iff there exists an sequence $x_n \in S$ s.t $\lim x_n =
> x$.

And I want to prove the fact that

$$\bar S = S \cup \operatorname{Ac}(S),$$ 
where $\operatorname{Ac}(S)$ is the set of all accumulation points of $S$.However, from the above propositions, I get that $bar S = \operatorname{Ac}(S)$. I mean I couldn't find where should the fact that $x_n \not = x_m$ for $n \not = m$ prevent me from stating this, so my question is **how can we prove that $\bar S = S \cup \operatorname{Ac}(S)$**

**Definition:**

$$\operatorname{Ac}(S) = \{ x\in E \mid \forall \epsilon > 0, [B(x, \epsilon) \setminus \{x\}] \cap S \not = \emptyset\}.$$

**Edit:**

Definition of closure;

$$\bar A = Int(A) \cup \partial (A),$$ i.e the union of the set of all interior points of $A$ and the boundary of $A$.

Comment: An accumulation point need not lie in the set itself. For example $\{\frac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\subset\Bbb R$ has $0$ as an accumulation point. But your definitions do not allow this.

Comment: @Yes, but $0$ is in the boundary of the set, hence in the closure.

Comment: I am pointing out that the two definitions of accumulation point you have given do not allow $0$ to be an accumulation point of the above set. The standard definition of an accumulation point _will_ have $0$ as an accumulation point, so what you have written as a definition is not what everybody else understands under the word accumulation point.

Comment: @s.harp Ok, I have corrected the definition.

Comment: Also the definition of closure is needed: the requested proof depends on it.

Comment: @egreg see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in\bar{A}$; then either $x\in\operatorname{Int}(A)$ or $x\in\partial(A)$. In any case, if $x\in A$, we have nothing to prove, so let's assume $x\notin A$ and $x\in\partial A$. By definition of boundary, each neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ (at a point distinct from $x$, as $x\notin A$). Therefore $x\in\operatorname{Ac}(A)$.

Similarly, suppose that $x\in A\cup\operatorname{Ac}(A)$ and that $x\notin\operatorname{Int}(A)$. Can you prove that $x\in\partial(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

Well, take $\{x\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean metric. We have $\overline{\{x\}} = \{x\}$, but $x$ is not an accumulation point of $\{x\}$. There does exist a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $x_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} x$, namely $x_n = x$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, but you cannot obtain a sequence in $\{x\}$ with distinct elements.

---

The inclusion $S \cup \mathrm{Ac}\,S \subseteq \overline{S}$ is obvious.

Let's prove $\overline{S} \subseteq S \cup \mathrm{Ac}\,S$. Assume that $x \in \overline{S}$ and $x \notin S$. We shall prove that $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

There exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $S$ which converges to $x$. Since $x \notin S$, there exists an elment $x_{p(1)}$ in the sequence such that $x_{p(1)} \ne x$.

Take $\varepsilon_1 = d(x, x_{p(1)}) > 0$. There exists $n_{\varepsilon_1} \in \mathbb{N}$, $n_{\varepsilon_1} > p(1)$ such that $n \ge n_{\varepsilon_1} \implies d(x, x_n) < \varepsilon_1$. Define $x_{p(2)} = x_{n_{\varepsilon_1}}$. It certainly holds $x_{p(2)} \ne x_{p(1)}$ since $d(x, x_{p(2)}) < d(x, x_{p(1)})$.

Take $\varepsilon_2 = d(x, x_{p(2)}) > 0$. There exists $n_{\varepsilon_2} \in \mathbb{N}$, $n_{\varepsilon_2} > p(2)$ such that $n \ge n_{\varepsilon_2} \implies d(x, x_n) < \varepsilon_2$. Define $x_{p(3)} = x_{n_{\varepsilon_2}}$. It certainly holds $x_{p(3)} \ne x_{p(1)}, x_{p(2)}$ since $d(x, x_{p(3)}) < d(x, x_{p(2)}) < d(x, x_{p(1)})$.

Now continue inductively in the same manner. You obtain a sequence $(x_{p(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ in $S$, with all distinct elements since $d(x, x_{p(n)})$ is strictly decreasing. It also converges to $x$ as it is a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Hence, $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Your definition of an accumulation point is wrong, it should be:
$$\mathrm{Ac}\,S = \{x \in E : \forall\varepsilon > 0 \text{ holds } (B(x, \varepsilon)\setminus \{x\}) \cap S \ne \emptyset\}$$

Comment: I did not know how to write backslash in MathJax, so I just put "$-$" instead :)

Comment: @onurcanbektas I'm not referring to that, I'm referring to the fact that it must be $x \in E$, not $x \in S$. That is the issue pointed out by s.harp.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: By the way, don't get me wrong, I just  saying for a kindly feedback, but the notation that you are using is hard to read and understand.